# Hallow most of the world achievement

Tags: achievements, terraria-console

In Terraria for Xbox One, there is an achievement called "Hallow most of the world." How much of the world do I need to hallow to get this achievement? I want to know because my world is already 23% hallow and I don't have much world left to hallow.

Comment: The underground counts too, you're probably missing a lot of that.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Can't hallow that. Already tried

Comment: By "tried" do you mean Hallow Grass Seeds? You can't plant those underground, but the hallow will spread from pearlstone as well.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I used my cleminator with blue solution

Comment: The Cavern level counts too. That's mostly stone. Which most definitely can be Hallowed. Underground dirt, not so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 50%

The Console achievement **Hallowed Be Thy Name** requires your world to be at least 50% Hallow. The [Dryad](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dryad) NPC can tell you how much of the world is Corrupt/Crimson or Hallow.

If you're looking for more area to Hallow, remember to spread Hallow to the underground areas as well. The [Cavern](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cavern) layer, which is primarily composed of stone, is where you'll do most of your underground work. [Hallowed Seeds](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hallowed_Seeds) can be used to spread the Hallow on the surface, but you'll want to use the [Clentaminator](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Clentaminator) with the [Blue Solution](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blue_Solution) to spread the Hallow to stone blocks underground in a timely manner.

Source: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Achievements#Xbox_360

Comment: Thanks. Now I need to hallow 27% more of my world to get the achievement.